# How many people can a Telegram bot serve at the same time

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I did not find information on limits on the simultaneous use of telegram bots, I mean how much people can use my telegram bot at the same time? I use webhook btw.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the overall performance mostly depends on your server performance.

However, there are limits on sending messages to users:

> When sending messages inside a particular chat, avoid sending more than one message per second. We may allow short bursts that go over this limit, but eventually you'll begin receiving 429 errors.

You can read about it in [this section of API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users).

Comment: I saw that by default webhook can serve only 40 users, is it true?

Comment: 40 is the default value for `max_connections` parameter of `setWebhook` method. You can set it explicitly by yourself, the maximum value is 100.

Comment: It represents the *Maximum allowed number of simultaneous HTTPS connections to the webhook for update deliver*.